# Move selected information form one TXT file to ANOTHER

Tags: shell-script

I have two txt files: config.txt and template.txt

template.txt has to take relevant information from config.txt

Let's say config.txt contains:

```
colour1: red
colour2: blue
```

And template.txt contains:

```
colour1:
colour2:
```

Is it possible to 'link' these two files, so template.txt takes the information from appropriate headings from config.txt and we end up with

template.txt

```
colour1: red
colour2: blue
```

Comment: Depending on how much functionality you need, this could be accomplished with a `symlink` or with a `perl` script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your use case, you can probably just use `grep -f`. You can search the file `config.txt` for the lines in `template.txt`, and it will give you the matching lines.

I.e.:

```
$ cat config.txt
color1: red
color2: blue
color3: green
color4: purple
color5: orange
foo: bar
$ cat template.txt
color1:
color2:
color5:
$ grep -f template.txt config.txt
color1: red
color2: blue
color5: orange
```

Note that you *can't* just do `grep -f template.txt config.txt > template.txt`, as the shell will wipe `template.txt` before `grep` runs. You would need to use a temporary file to get around that.